# Binding to subscript doesn't update TextField (macOS)

Tags: swift, macos, swiftui

I have this `Store` struct, which is a wrapper for all my data. It has a subscript operator which takes in a `UUID`, and returns the associated object.

This way, I can have a `List` bind to a selection variable, which has type `UUID`, and then in another view I can access the selected object from that `UUID`.

However, I'm experiencing an issue where my `TextField` which binds to the `Store` doesn't update. It does update if I wrap it in another `Binding`, or if I instead just use `Text`.

Here is an minimal reproducible example:

```
struct Person: Identifiable, Hashable {
    let id = UUID()
    var name: String
}

struct Store {
    var data: [Person]
    
    subscript(id: Person.ID) -> Person {
        get {
            data.first(where: { $0.id == id })!
        }
        set {
            data[data.firstIndex(where: { $0.id == id })!] = newValue
        }
    }
}

struct ContentView: View {
    @State var store = Store(data: [
        Person(name: "Joe"),
        Person(name: "Eva"),
        Person(name: "Sam"),
        Person(name: "Mary")
    ])
    @State var selection: Person.ID?
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            List(store.data, selection: $selection) {
                Text($0.name)
            }
            
            if let selection = selection {
                // Creating a new Binding which simply wraps $store[selection].name
                // fixes this issue. Or just using Text also works.
                TextField("Placeholder", text: $store[selection].name)
            }
            else {
                Text("No Selection")
            }
        }
    }
}
```

To reproduce this issue, just click different names on the Sidebar. For some reason the detail view's `TextField` doesn't update!

This issue can also be resolved if we simply move the `Store` to a `ObservableObject` class with `@Published`.

Also, making the `Store` conform to `Hashable` doesn't help this issue.

I feel like I'm missing something very basic with `SwiftUI`. Is there any way to fix this?

**EDIT**:
I've changed out `Store` for an `[Person]`, and I made an extension with the same subscript operator that is in `Store`. However, the problem still remains!

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Im on macOS though

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

```
TextField("Placeholder", text: $store[selection].name)
    .id(selection)  // <-- here
```

Comment: Thank you! This works well! But I was wondering, what was wrong in the original code?

Comment: I may be wrong, but as I understand it, this will "force" the view to re-render.

Comment: I think you're right about that. That's why the code also works if you wrap the Binding in another Binding, and also inside of an ObservableObject. However, I was wondering why didn't the original code work? I.e. what was wrong with the original code?

Comment: adding `.id(selection)` makes the view (TextField) unique, and so the when the container view updates, it 
sees that this view is no longer the same as before and re-do it. See also https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swiftui/view/id(_:), the discussion part

Comment: Ahhhhhh, that makes sense. Thank you! But how come the `TextField` isn't able to figure out that something has changed here, but it is when I wrap in a Binding, like this: Binding(get: { originalBinding.wrappedValue }, set: { originalBinding.wrappedValue = $0 })?

Comment: don't know. If my solution answers your question, could you mark it as correct please. (the tick mark)

Comment: Oops! I forgot about that! I marked it now. Thank you for your help!

Comment: The reason it isn't updating is that you are using two structs. There is no publisher involved. If `Store` was a class that conformed to `ObservableObject` and `data` was `@Published` it would update correctly. Using the `.id()` works around this.

Comment: @Yrb However I was under the assumption that SwiftUI can monitor Structs for changes, assuming it conforms to Hashable. For example, SwiftUI can monitor Arrays for changes, which are structs.

Comment: @Yrb See edits. I dumped the `Store` struct and am using Array directly. I made an extension for `Array<Person>`, which has the same subscript operator as in the original Store. However, the issue still remains.

Comment: The you have 2 levels of structs. The one struct doesn't notify the next. We have the same sort of problem with nested `ObservableObjects`.

Comment: @Yrb But I switched out the Store and am using an [Person] directly, with a subscript operator as an extension. The issue still remains, but there is only 1 level of struct